# Пронумеровать повторяющиеся значения в списке / Python

Tags: python

Нужно последовательно пронумеровать повторяющиеся значения в списке

**Пример:**

- Яблоко
- Груша
- Слива
- Вишня
- Яблоко
- Груша

  **Нужно получить:**
- Яблоко 1
- Груша 1
- Яблоко 2
- Вишня 1
- Яблоко 3
- Груша 2
- Вишня 2

**И тд.**

Comment: Берёте словарь и храните в нём счётчики для каждого уникального элемента вашего списка.

Comment: Для этого удобно использовать `defaultdict`, но можно и обычный словарь

Answer (score 3):

```
fruit_list = ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Plum', 'Cherry', 'Apple', 'Pear']

res = {}
for fruit in fruit_list:
    if fruit not in res:
        res[fruit] = 1
    else:
        res[fruit] += 1
    print(fruit, str(res[fruit]))
```

Output:

```
Apple 1
Pear 1
Plum 1
Cherry 1
Apple 2
Pear 2
```

Comment: Можно использовать более короткую конструкцию вместо всего тела цикла: `res[fruit] = res.get(fruit, 0) + 1`